# javascript code hanging the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the position of a moving div(animated using css3 animations) and for checking it continuously I am using a `while(true)` like below

```
function detectCollision(){

    alert(document.getElementById("obstacle").style.left)

    while(true){
        var temp = getObstaclePosition();

        var temp2 = getPlanePosition();
        if(temp[0] <= temp2[0]+500){
            document.getElementsByClassName("plane")[0].style.display = "none";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that after the first alert the page hangs. Moreover if I put an alert in the while loop then it keeps on popping up and the code works fine but not otherwise.
Let me know how I can fix this?

Comment: don't use `while(true)`, use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Nothing in the loop ever changes `temp[0]`, so nothing will make the loop ever exit.

Comment: While loop is just going to lock up your browser which will prevent other processes to run. You need to use intervals or timeouts to prevent the locking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `while (true)`, which is costly, you can use `setInterval`:

```
a = setInterval(function () {
    var temp = getObstaclePosition();

    var temp2 = getPlanePosition();
    if(temp[0] <= temp2[0]+500){
        document.getElementsByClassName("plane")[0].style.display = "none";
        clearInterval(a);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: This won't work the way you've done it, what if the if statement returns `false`, nothing happens.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Which statment?

Comment: 'the the statement', made an edit to fix this typo haha

Answer (score 2):

The page does not render while you are inside that loop, and thus the position of the element will not change. This results in the loop never ending.

If you want to do something like this, you will have to be using a *recursive* `setTimeout` or a normal `setInterval` implementation.

With them, do one check per timeout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript runs in one and the same thread, so if some loop occupies this with an infinite loop, the rest is not able to run anymore.

As an alternative to your loop, you could use `setInterval`, which repeatedly executes a function or code snippet:

```
setInterval(new function() {
    // whatever
}, 100); // repeat every 100 ms, i.e. 10 times per second
```